# If $p^\text{th}$ term of an AP is $q$ and $q^\text{th}$ term of the AP is $p$, find its $r^\text{th}$ term.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, arithmetic-progressions

If $p^\text{th}$ term of an A.P is $q$ and $q^\text{th}$ term of the A.P is $p$, how do you find its $r^\text{th}$ term.

This is the solution where I'm stuck at.

From the question we get $a_p=q$ & value of $a_q=p$, where $a$ is the Arithmetic equation.

So,

$a_p=a_1+(p-1)d \rightarrow q$

$a_q=a_1+(q-1)d \rightarrow p$

By substituting the value of $p$ in the first equation ie, $a_p$. We get:-

$a_p=a_1+(a_1+(q-1)d)d=q$

$a_p=a_1+(a_1+dq-d)d=q$

$a_p=a_1+a_1d+d^2q-d^2=q$

- Hoping I'm doing this correctly till now, but can't seem to know what do next.
- And how do you find the $r^\text{th}$ term?

Comment: $(a_1 + (q - 1)d)d \neq a_1 + dq - d$.  I think it should be
$$(a_1 + (q - 1)d)d = a_1 d + d^2 q - d^2$$
instead.

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebita-Dris Okay could you please tell me what to do next. I have no clue.

Comment: Please check out my answer below, @AsheDanni.  Nice problem, by the way!  =)

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$a_p = a_1 + (p - 1)d = q$$
and
$$a_q = a_1 + (q - 1)d = p.$$

Subtracting the two equations, you get:
$$a_p - a_q = (p - q)d = q - p.$$

Assuming WLOG that $p \neq q$, then we obtain that the common difference
$$d = -1.$$

Substituting $d=-1$ into the first two equations, we obtain
$$a_p = a_1 - (p - 1) = q$$
and
$$a_q = a_1 - (q - 1) = p.$$

Thus, we have
$$a_1 + 1 = p + q,$$
or in other words
$$a_1 = (p + q) - 1.$$

Consequently, the $r$th term is given by the expression
$$a_r = a_1 + (r - 1)d = (p + q) - 1 + (r - 1)\cdot{-1} = p + q - 1 + 1 - r = p + q - r.$$